# Select elements based on two conditions - jQuery

Tags: jquery

Could someone please help me select anchors that respect two conditions. For one condition, I wrote the following line and it works:

```
$links = $('a[data-one="' + one + '"]');
```

I tried following things:

```
$links = $('a[data-one="' + one + '", data-two="' + two + '"]');

$links = $('a[data-one="' + one + '"] a[data-two="'+ two+ '"]');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select an element by two attributes you should combine the attribute selectors with no space:

```
// using concatenation:
$links = $('a[data-one="' + one + '"][data-two="'+ two+ '"]');

// using string interpolation
$links = $(`a[data-one="${one}"][data-two="${two}"]`);
```

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I understand and it is working. Waiting for timer to expire +1

Answer (score 2):

Remove the comma and space

```
$links = $('a[data-one="' + one + '"][data-two="'+ two+ '"]');
```

The comma is for a **new** selector while the space is for **descendant** selector

However, leaving no space applies the conditions on the **current** preceding condition(if any)